# Can validation rules be bypassed in forms?

Tags: django, validation, forms

I've got a simple newsletter app with a subscription model with fields email and city.
In this model I set unique_together('email', 'city') to avoid having subscription duplicates.

```
class Subscription(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=75)
    create_date = models.DateField(_("Creation Date"))
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('email', 'city')
```

I created a forms.ModelForm from this model:

```
class SubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
```

This is ok when I create a subscription, but when I want to delete a subscription, using the same form, the form does not validate when setting an existing email/subject pair because of the unique_together in the model. Is there any way to bypass this validation rule or should I write a specific form to unsubscribe?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably override the `unique_together` in your `SubscriptionForm` but this will remove the validation from your form (and will fail when you will save your model).
Or you can create a new `UnSubscriptionForm` that will override this `unique_together` setting only for unsubscription.